# How does :global in styled-jsx work in React.js?

Tags: css, reactjs

I do not understand the logic of :global() when working with classes from various different components using React.js.

- what goes before the :global() syntax? and what within the brackets?

  .select :global(.select__value) {
  some css
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change css code of some global class name component generally you should inspect your element to see what is the class name of that element and in brackets you should put that class name.

For example if you do directly `:global(.select__value)` it will effect this component's css as global. But if you do `.classNameFather :global(.select__value)` it will effect just this component in classNameFather instead of global change.